# raster area in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a raster file (10*10). It has 3 columns and 4 rows. I have a column Count that gives me number of cells in each row class (0,1,2,3). I want to get area of this raster in R. I ma thinking of adding the cell counts and then multiply by 100 to get area in square meters. I tried using area(rastername) but got an error saying Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) :
  This function is only useful for Raster* objects with a longitude/latitude coordinates.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: area() works fine for non-longlat grids - it's just a warning - but you need to now worry whether your constant pixel width/height area matches the reality of your projection. It probably is fine given how tiny it is . . .   What is the projection() and extent() of the grid?   If the projection is equal area, or covers relatively small region all is well, but you will find a discrepancy for large areas  if the projection is conformal or equi-distant rather than equal-area.

Answer (score 4):

area function of raster will work if your raster is in latitude and longitude coordinate system. You can try this 
`library(raster)`
`r = raster("path to file")`
`area = nrow(r)  * ncol(r)  * xres(r) * yres(r)`

Comment: My raster is in UTM. Can't we specify R to add counts in one of the columns and so the math?

Comment: I am not getting your question. What count you want to keep in column ?  Also area() function will work in UTM projections also, area function will return raster of same size as input raster with each pixel stores the area of that pixel in square km.